# Given a numpy array image, how can I remove colored pixels (R,G,B) != (0,0,0) that are surrounded by black pixels (R,G,B) = (0,0,0)?

Tags: image, opencv, numpy, computer-vision

I wrote a method that takes a camera image of a person, determines the pixels that make up the person, and sets all other pixels to (0,0,0). This new image shows the person surrounded by black pixels.

These images have the shape (500,500,3), where the first 2 dimensions make up the width and height of the image and 3 represents the channels (R,G,B).

What I'd like to do next is remove noise. There are a few pixels incorrectly classified as belonging to the person. In other words, these are pixels surrounded by black pixels.

**How can I remove these "lone pixels" which have color, but are surrounded by black pixels (0,0,0)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joe suggests I would also use convolution, but with a different kernel `np.ones((3,3))`:

```
1 1 1
1 1 1 
1 1 1
```

First you convert your array into a boolean array of shape 500X500

With something like: `bool_arr = np.sum(arr, axis = -1)!=0`, black pixels will be `False`, all others will be `True`. (For an alternative, faster version see comments)

```
import scipy.signal
conv_arr = scipy.signal.convolve2d(bool_arr, np.ones((3,3)), 'same')
wrong_pixels = conv_arr == 1 # only one of the 9 pixels is colored
pixels[wrong_pixels] = [0,0,0] # color all the wrong ones black
```

Comment: With `bool_arr = np.sum(arr, axis = -1)==0`, all the black pixels will be `True`.  If you want that functionality (and much more efficiently) try `bool_arr = np.logical_not(np.logical_or.accumulate(arr, axis = -1))`

Comment: Thanks, you are indeed correct. I will leave my version though, because I think it's easier to read/understand and doubt that performance is such a big issue, as the array is quite small.

Comment: The benefit of Joe's convolution is also that you can do `wrong_pixels = ~conv_arr.astype(bool)`, since any integer other than `0` will resolve to `True` without the comparison.  Much faster.  You'll also be overwriting a lot of black pixels that are adjacent to a colored pixel.

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak should the last parameter in convolve2d be "same". That reduces the array to (3,3) even though you'd want it to remain the full size, no?

Comment: @megashigger "same" is the correct parameter. It tells convolve to return an array with the same shape as in1. The two arrays should be in the different order, first bool_arr and then np.ones((3,3)), changed that in the edit

Answer (score 1):

You could use a convolution with a 3 x 3 kernel if you want solution without for-loops.

Kernel should look something like

```
1 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
```

Or you could use Morphological Image Processing, the operation "Closing" should work. Maybe "Erosion" too.

[Morphological Image Processing](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm)